# Add URL path to static resource in javascript (in Spring MVC )

Tags: javascript, spring

I have javascript file in Spring MVC project. I connected this file to jsp by next tag: `<script src="<c:url value="/resource/JS/controllers.js"/>"></script>`
It's worked correct but now I want add image to javascript. Something like this:

```
var image = 'startIcon.png';
  var startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: centerLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });
```

But this code doesn't work. Pleaese healp me! How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the image just using the name, js will look for the image in same folder. Hence you need to first get the `contextpath` of your application then refer the image with that url, you can do this by adding the below code in the jsp.

```
<script>var ctx = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}"</script>
```

Then you can prefix `image` with ctx

```
var image = ctx + '/images/startIcon.png';
```